# Is there a way to create a new column in R that is the value of two other columns combined?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-wrangling

My data looks as follows:

| Line.item.name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2 Vegan PDN | 123 |
| 1 Vegan PDN | 208 |
| 4 Vegan PDN | 8 |
| 6 Vegan PDN | 2 |

```
structure(list(Line.item.name = c("2 Vegan PDN", "1 Vegan PDN", 
"4 Vegan PDN", "6 Vegan PDN"), Quantity = c(123L, 208L, 8L, 2L
), actual_quantity = c(246, 208, 32, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

My main goal here is to create a new column called "actual_quantity" which shows me the true quantity sold. For instance, 2 Vegan PDN means I told two and the quantity of that occurance was 123 times. Therefore, my actual quantity of Vegan PDN is 246. I would like to do this for each item in Line.item.name so the data frame looks like this:

| Line.item.name | Quantity | actual_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 Vegan PDN | 123 | 246 |
| 1 Vegan PDN | 208 | 208 |
| 4 Vegan PDN | 8 | 32 |
| 6 Vegan PDN | 2 | 12 |

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to get the number out of the first column, e.g. using `parse_number()` from the `readr` package. Perhaps something like `df$actual_quantity <- df$Quantity * readr::parse_number(df$Line.item.name)`

Comment: Similar idea as Axeman, just in base R: `df$actual_quantity <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$Line.item.name)) * df$Quantity`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mutate` from `dplyr`:

```
tibble::tibble(Line.item.name = c("2 Vegan PDN", "1 Vegan PDN", "4 Vegan PDN", "6 Vegan PDN"),
       Quantity = c(123L, 208L, 8L, 2L)) %>% 
  mutate(actual_quantity = parse_number(Line.item.name) * Quantity)
```

result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Line.item.name Quantity actual_quantity
  <chr>             <int>           <dbl>
1 2 Vegan PDN         123             246
2 1 Vegan PDN         208             208
3 4 Vegan PDN           8              32
4 6 Vegan PDN           2              12
```